# Battery not detected, /proc/acpi/battery empty even it is present

Tags: boot, dual-boot, power-management, battery, nouveau

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and it is fully up-to-date. But the battery of my laptop is never detected. There is no battery icon on the top bar, the `/proc/acpi/battery` is empty.

I've tried to remove the battery from my laptop and boot, then the `/proc/acpi/battery` has a directory BAT0 with 4 files, each of these files contains only 'off-line'. Then I charged my battery on again and reboot, and the `/proc/acpi/battery` is empty again.
What's more, every time I boot Ubuntu there will be at least two error messages:

```
[11.072582] nouveau E[DEVICE][0000:01:00.0] unknown chipset, 0x118010a2
[11.073360] nouveau E[   DRM] failed to create 0x80000080, -22
```

and when I tried to charge my battery on again and boot, There was one more error message about a DEVICE, but it disappeared soon so I didn't see clearly what it is about.

I'm using dual-system on my laptop, the other OS is Windows 7.
I really need some help!